# Lowres application icon on window switching (alt-tab)

Tags: gnome, linux-mint, icons, cinnamon

I manually downloaded and installed Sublime Text 2 (instead of adding the repository and installing via `apt-get install`) and I'm having some trouble getting gnome to find the high res icons for sublime.

I extracted the application to `/usr/lib/sublime-text`
Added the following executable script as `/usr/bin/sublime`

```
#!/bin/sh
export SUBLIME_HOME="/usr/lib/sublime-text"
$SUBLIME_HOME/sublime_text $*
```

The `/usr/lib/sublime-text/Icon` directory contains icons for various resolutions in subdirectories (16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 128x128, 256x256), and I used the 256x256 one when I added the menu item to the cinnamon menu.

How does Gnome locate the icon for an application? I renamed the `/etc/lib/sublime-text/Icon` directory and then I didn't get an icon at all (default gnome icon) so

Gnome's obviously using an icon from the `/usr/lib/sublime-text` folder, but if so why how do I get it to use a highres one?
Also how does Gnome match the application to the image name? Currently the script in `/usr/bin` is named `sublime`, the directory in `/usr/lib` is named `sublime-text`, the executable in `/usr/bin/lib/sublime-text` is named `sublime_text` and the menu item is defined in a file named `Sublime Text.desktop`.

I seriously don't understand how the system manages to match all of this...

---

I'm running Linux Mint 13 (Cinnamon)

Comment: Hi. I have this problem on Fedora20 and was wondering if you managed to solve this? I have a desktop file for sublime at ~/.local/share/applications/sublime.desktop which points to the 256x256 icon, but it still uses the low-rew icon when switching applications with alt tab.

Answer (score 3):

While this isn't the best solution, I get around the problem of low resolution icons by just pointing directly to the highest possible version inside the .desktop file. In this case specifically, I have it pointing to a local copy of the official 256px icon, but any location should work.

```
Icon=/home/patrick/.icons/sublime-256.png
```

Answer (score 2):

I copied the Sublime icons over to the various directories `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/[NxN]/apps`

Then I made a sublime.desktop file and put it under `~/.local/share/applications`, with `Icon=sublime_text`.

That seemed to work.