# Tab switcher icons blurry (Linux mint)

Tags: linux-mint, icons

I know this has been asked before but nothing is working for me. My sublime text icon in the tab switcher is blurry. I have tried to set the icon in /opt/sublime_text/Icon` to an svg with no luck. I am using Linux mint 17.2 64 bit.

[image]

Comment: Related: [This old post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40465/125388) asked on "Lowres application icon on window switching (alt-tab)" for manually installed Sublime Text on Linux Mint 13 and has several answers. Is this no longer working on Linux Mint 17.X?

Comment: To avoid repetition, can you describe what you've tried already.

Comment: @EightBitTony I tried referencing a 512x512 png directly in the .desktop file. I also tried to set it to an svg.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with PyCharm icon.

If you have created your own launcher for the application (`.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications`) you need to make sure, that you have correct `StartupWMClass` attribute set.

To find the proper value, start your application, then open the terminal and run `xprop WM_CLASS` and click on your application window. Make sure that the value from the terminal matches the `StartupWMClass` in your launcher. Restart the app, and you should see the correct icon.